# azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine - already exists

Tags: sql, azure, terraform

Trying to do an AZ Terraform deployment, and failing horribly - looking for some ideas what am I missing. Basically I am trying to deploy 2 (maybe later more) VM-s with variable size of disks, joining them to the domain and add SQL server to them. (Be gentle with me, I am from VMWare-Tf background, this is my first SQL deployment on AZ!)

My module:

```
## main.tf:

# ----------- NIC --------------------------------
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "${var.vm_name}-nic"
  resource_group_name = var.rg.name
  location            = var.location
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.vm_name}-internal"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = var.private_ip
  }
  dns_servers = var.dns_servers
}
# ----------- VM --------------------------------
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  /* count   = length(var.instances) */
  name                     = var.vm_name
  location                 = var.location
  resource_group_name      = var.rg.name
  network_interface_ids    = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  size                     = var.size
  zone                     = var.zone
  admin_username           = var.win_admin_user
  admin_password           = var.win_admin_pw # data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.vmadminpwd.value
  enable_automatic_updates = "false"
  patch_mode               = "Manual"
  provision_vm_agent       = "true"
  tags                     = var.vm_tags

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
    offer     = "sql2019-ws2019"
    sku       = "enterprise"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${var.vm_name}-osdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = 250
  }
}

# ----------- DOMAIN JOIN --------------------------------
// Waits for up to 1 hour for the Domain to become available. Will return an error 1 if unsuccessful preventing the member attempting to join.
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "wait-for-domain-to-provision" {
  name                 = "TestConnectionDomain"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  settings             = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"while (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName ${var.active_directory_domain_name} -Count 1 -Quiet) -and ($retryCount++ -le 360)) { Start-Sleep 10 } \""
  }
SETTINGS
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "join-domain" {
  name                 = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.name
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "JsonADDomainExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.3"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  settings             = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Name": "${var.active_directory_domain_name}",
        "OUPath": "",
        "User": "${var.active_directory_username}@${var.active_directory_domain_name}",
        "Restart": "true",
        "Options": "3"
    }
SETTINGS
  protected_settings   = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "Password": "${var.active_directory_password}"
    }
SETTINGS
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.wait-for-domain-to-provision]
}
# ----------- DISKS --------------------------------
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "data" {
  for_each             = var.disks
  name                 = "${var.vm_name}-${each.value.name}"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.rg.name
  storage_account_type = each.value.sa
  create_option        = each.value.create
  disk_size_gb         = each.value.size
  zone                 = var.zone
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "disk-attachment" {
  for_each           = var.disks
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.data[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  lun                = each.value.lun
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
  depends_on         = [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm]
}
# ----------- SQL --------------------------------
# configure the SQL side of the deployment
resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
  /* count = length(var.instances) */
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  sql_license_type      = "PAYG"
  r_services_enabled    = true
  sql_connectivity_port = 1433
  sql_connectivity_type = "PRIVATE"
  /* sql_connectivity_update_username = var.sqladmin
    sql_connectivity_update_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sqladminpwd.value */

  #The storage_configuration block supports the following:
  storage_configuration {
    disk_type             = "NEW"  # (Required) The type of disk configuration to apply to the SQL Server. Valid values include NEW, EXTEND, or ADD.
    storage_workload_type = "OLTP" # (Required) The type of storage workload. Valid values include GENERAL, OLTP, or DW.

    data_settings {
      default_file_path = "F:\\Data"
      luns              = [1]
    }

    log_settings {
      default_file_path = "G:\\Log"
      luns              = [2]
    }

    temp_db_settings {
      default_file_path = "D:\\TempDb"
      luns              = [0]
    }

  }
}

## provider.tf

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.0.1"
      #configuration_aliases = [azurerm.corp]
    }
  }
}

variables.tf

# ----------- COMMON --------------------------------
variable "vm_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "rg" {
  /* type = string */
  description = "STACK - resource group"
}
variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "STACK - location"
}
# ----------- NIC --------------------------------
variable "subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "STACK - subnet"
}
variable "private_ip" {
}
variable "dns_servers" {
}
# ----------- VM --------------------------------
variable "size" {
  description = "VM - size"
  type        = string
}
variable "win_admin_user" {
  sensitive = true
  type      = string
}
variable "win_admin_pw" {
  sensitive = true
  type      = string
}
variable "os_storage_type" {
  type = string
}
variable "vm_tags" {
  type = map(any)
}
variable "zone" {
  #type = list
  description = "VM AZ"
}
# ----------- DOMAIN JOIN --------------------------------
variable "active_directory_domain_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "active_directory_username" {
  sensitive = true
}
variable "active_directory_password" {
  sensitive = true
}
# ----------- SQL --------------------------------
variable "sql_maint_day" {
  type        = string
  description = "SQL -  maintenance day"
}
variable "sql_maint_length_min" {
  type        = number
  description = "SQL - maintenance duration (min)"
}
variable "sql_maint_start_hour" {
  type        = number
  description = "SQL-  maintenance start (hour of the day)"
}
# ----------- DISKS --------------------------------
/* variable "disk_storage_account" {
  type        = string
  default     = "Standard_LRS"
  description = "DATA DISKS - storage account type"
}
variable "disk_create_method" {
  type        = string
  default     = "Empty"
  description = "DATA DISKS - creation method"
}
variable "disk_size0" {
  type = number
}
variable "disk_size1" {
  type = number
}
variable "disk_size2" {
  type = number
}
variable "lun0" {
  type    = number
  default = 0
}
variable "lun1" {
  type    = number
  default = 1
}
variable "lun2" {
  default = 2
  type    = number
} */

/* variable "disks" {
  description = "List of disks to create"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    disk0 = {
      name   = "data0"
      size   = 200
      create = "Empty"
      sa     = "Standard_LRS"
      lun    = 0
    }
    disk1 = {
      name   = "data1"
      size   = 500
      create = "Empty"
      sa     = "Standard_LRS"
      lun    = 1
    }
  }
} */

variable "disks" {
  type = map(object({
    name   = string
    size   = number
    create = string
    sa     = string
    lun    = number
  }))
}
```

the actual deployment:

```
main.tf
/*
PS /home/fabrice> Get-AzVMSize -Location northeurope | where-object {$_.Name -like "*ds13*"}
*/
module "uat_set" {
  source = "../modules/vm"
  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm.cbank-test
  }
  for_each                     = var.uat_set
  active_directory_domain_name = local.uat_ad_domain
  active_directory_password    = var.domain_admin_password
  active_directory_username    = var.domain_admin_username
  disks                        = var.disk_allocation
  dns_servers                  = local.dns_servers
  location                     = local.uat_location
  os_storage_type              = local.uat_storage_type
  private_ip                   = each.value.private_ip
  rg                           = data.azurerm_resource_group.main
  size                         = each.value.vm_size
  sql_maint_day                = local.uat_sql_maintenance_day
  sql_maint_length_min         = local.uat_sql_maintenance_min
  sql_maint_start_hour         = local.uat_sql_maintenance_start_hour
  subnet_id                    = data.azurerm_subnet.main.id
  vm_name                      = each.key
  vm_tags                      = var.default_tags
  win_admin_pw                 = var.admin_password
  win_admin_user               = var.admin_username
  zone                         = each.value.zone[0]
}
variable "uat_set" {
  description = "List of VM-s to create"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    UAT-SQLDB-NE-01 = {
      private_ip = "192.168.32.8"
      vm_size    = "Standard_DS13-4_v2"
      zone       = ["1"]
    }
    UAT-SQLDB-NE-02 = {
      private_ip = "192.168.32.10"
      vm_size    = "Standard_DS13-4_v2"
      zone       = ["2"]
    }
  }
}
variable "disk_allocation" {
  type = map(object({
    name   = string
    size   = number
    create = string
    sa     = string
    lun    = number
  }))
  default = {
    "temp" = {
      name   = "temp"
      size   = 200
      create = "Empty"
      sa     = "Standard_LRS"
      lun    = 0
    },
    "disk1" = {
      name   = "data1"
      size   = 500
      create = "Empty"
      sa     = "Standard_LRS"
      lun    = 1
    },
    "disk2" = {
      name   = "data2"
      size   = 500
      create = "Empty"
      sa     = "Standard_LRS"
      lun    = 2
    }
  }
}
locals {
  dns_servers                    = ["192.168.34.5", "192.168.34.10"]
  uat_storage_type               = "Standard_LRS"
  uat_sql_maintenance_day        = "Saturday"
  uat_sql_maintenance_min        = 180
  uat_sql_maintenance_start_hour = 23
  uat_ad_domain                  = "civbdev.local"
  uat_location                   = "North Europe"
}

## variables.tf

# new build variables
variable "Environment" {
  default     = "DEV"
  description = "this is the environment variable used to intperpolate with others vars"
}
variable "default_tags" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    Environment = "DEV"
    Product     = "dev-XXXtemplateXXX"
    Terraformed = "https://AllicaBankLtd@dev.azure.com/XXXtemplateXXX/Terraform/DEV"
  }
}
variable "admin_username" {
  sensitive = true
}
variable "admin_password" {
  sensitive = true
}
variable "domain_admin_username" {
  sensitive = true
}
variable "domain_admin_password" {
  sensitive = true
}
```

Resources create OK, except the SQL-part

```
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<..redacted...>/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/sqlVirtualMachines/UAT-SQLDB-NE-02" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" for more information.
│ 
│   with module.uat_set["UAT-SQLDB-NE-02"].azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.sqlvm,
│   on ../modules/vm/main.tf line 115, in resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm":
│  115: resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<..redacted...>/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/sqlVirtualMachines/UAT-SQLDB-NE-01" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" for more information.
│ 
│   with module.uat_set["UAT-SQLDB-NE-01"].azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.sqlvm,
│   on ../modules/vm/main.tf line 115, in resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm":
│  115: resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
│ 
╵
```

Any notions please what I might be missing?

Ta,
Fabrice

UPDATE:

Thanks for those who replied. Just to confirm: it is not an already existing resource. I get this error straight at the time of the creation of these VM-s.

For example, these are my vm-s after the Terraform run (none of them has the sql extension)

[image]

[image]

Plan even states it will create these:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.uat_set["UAT-SQLDB-NE-01"].azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.sqlvm will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + r_services_enabled    = true
      + sql_connectivity_port = 1433
      + sql_connectivity_type = "PRIVATE"
      + sql_license_type      = "PAYG"
      + virtual_machine_id    = "/subscriptions/..../providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/UAT-SQLDB-NE-01"

      + storage_configuration {
          + disk_type             = "NEW"
          + storage_workload_type = "OLTP"

          + data_settings {
              + default_file_path = "F:\\Data"
              + luns              = [
                  + 1,
                ]
            }

          + log_settings {
              + default_file_path = "G:\\Log"
              + luns              = [
                  + 2,
                ]
            }

          + temp_db_settings {
              + default_file_path = "Z:\\TempDb"
              + luns              = [
                  + 0,
                ]
            }
        }
    }

  # module.uat_set["UAT-SQLDB-NE-02"].azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.sqlvm will be created
  + resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "sqlvm" {
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + r_services_enabled    = true
      + sql_connectivity_port = 1433
      + sql_connectivity_type = "PRIVATE"
      + sql_license_type      = "PAYG"
      + virtual_machine_id    = "/subscriptions/..../providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/UAT-SQLDB-NE-02"

      + storage_configuration {
          + disk_type             = "NEW"
          + storage_workload_type = "OLTP"

          + data_settings {
              + default_file_path = "F:\\Data"
              + luns              = [
                  + 1,
                ]
            }

          + log_settings {
              + default_file_path = "G:\\Log"
              + luns              = [
                  + 2,
                ]
            }

          + temp_db_settings {
              + default_file_path = "Z:\\TempDb"
              + luns              = [
                  + 0,
                ]
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Presumably, if these resources would exist somehow - which would be odd, as Tf just created the VM-s - then it would not say in the plan that it will create it now, would it?

So the error is quite the source of my confusion, since if the VM just got created, the creation of the extension failed - how could it possibly be existing? [image]

Comment: The error is clear. You have pre-existing resources. Did you create them manually?

Comment: Adding to what @Marcin said, there you have the answer with solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73745584/2128007

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform on GCP - Error 409: Requested entity already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73745130/terraform-on-gcp-error-409-requested-entity-already-exists)

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, but that is not my problem. I updated the original post. Basically this is happening at the initial run - when the VM-s are created - so how would you think it is possible that the extensions already exist? Also they do not show up on the extension page of the VM...if they would exist, presumably they should be there right?

Comment: Here's the problem: you are using `for_each` when calling the module. In the module itself, you are creating the SQL VM. Since the resource `azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine` is not unique in any way (no `count` or `for_each` blocks), Terraform sees that it already exists. So what I would suggest is moving the `for_each` into the module code rather than creating multiple instances of the same module.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE. Not sure how you mean this?
I am a bit confused on this one...
- so for the VMs (which are also in the same loop), it was not a problem, and they seen as unique? (same for the domain join extension), but it is problem for the SQL?
- I would have thoughts - since I am using `virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id` in the code of the sql vm - that it makes it unique? (admittedly this is the first time I am using this sql resource...)
- how exactly move the for_each into the module?

Comment: Hm, yes, that might not be an issue. The difference is that the other VMs have different names, while I don't see anything like that in your `azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine` resource. Is there a name which you could use to differentiate between two different VMs?

Comment: I could make up something - the `var.vm_name` should always be unique - but the azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine resource does not seem to have a name property, unless I am mistaken..?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should probably just import the modules as the error suggest to your terraform state.

For example
`terraform import module.uat_set[\"UAT-SQLDB-NE-02\"].azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine.sqlvm "/subscriptions/<..redacted...>/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/sqlVirtualMachines/UAT-SQLDB-NE-02"`